# "Related Permissions Module" settings

Tags: drupal, permissions, relationships, configuration

I installed the extension "Related Permissions Module", and now how do to configure the acl for single organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this extension provides is the ability to deliver access control via Relationships.

Hence if you make Relationship Type xxx a permissioned relationship and then make JOHN a manager for MYCO, and if MYCO has permissioned relationships for Mary and Bob, and you set CiviCRM permissions so that people with Role of Manager to not view/edit ALL contacts then John will be able to only see Mary and Bob, and not other contacts who have no relationship to MYCO

Comment: Adding this comment here from other questions "When the above extensions are enabled, on any Relationship Type you should now see a new field saying Always Permission A to B (and vv). And at civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 you should see an option for 'Allow second-degree relationship permissions'."

Comment: My doubt is this : it's possible create a drupal user and associate to a member organizations? and relationships created previously , via the acl can be associated only by means groups?

Comment: I don't think I understand your point, but my suggestion about using Relationships for your access control is not related to using the ACL Groups etc that civicrm offers. It is an independent approach

Comment: ok but then how I put Relationships in correlation with the acl ?

Comment: that is what the extension does so you don't need to create ACLs